# Is the graph of $ r = \dfrac{3 \pi}{5} $ a diagonal line?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm reviewing my notes and I came upon this. It says that
$$ \begin{align}
r \sin \theta &= 5 \tag{horizontal line} \\
r &= \dfrac{3 \pi}{5} \tag{diagonal line}
\end{align}$$
How is this possible, when $\dfrac{3 \pi}{5}$ results to a constant (therefore a straight line)?

Comment: You probably mean theta = 3 pi / 5.

Comment: $r=\frac{3\pi}{5}$ should be a circle of radius $\frac{3\pi}{5}$ as opposed to a diagonal line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation $r=k$ is the equation of a circle, centre the origin, radius $k$. So it would be a circle of radius $\frac{3\pi}{5}$. Odd radius!

You presumably meant $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{5}$, which (depending on whether we don't allow negative $r$ or do) is a half-line or a full line.

Comment: Ah. Now I remember our instructor retracting her answer to this particular question. She did say it was a circle. Thanks!